# Problems with Deja-Dup

Tags: dejadup

I am having difficulty restoring a backup with deja-dup. I am also having difficulty understanding the advice given in the help documentation that comes with the software.

I think the problem I am having is that I did not have write permissions for any of the files when I was backing up the folders.[image: This image displays the error message].

The particular files that are displayed weren't screencaptured for any particular reason: none of the files in the backup were restored.

The part of the help documentation I am having problems understanding is the following.

The help documentation states "Some versions of Déjà Dup will not correctly restore files stored in a folder that you did not have write access to when you backed them up" and the advice it gives is to try to create a temp file and restore the files there. But I don't understand, since no matter where I restore the files to now, the files still did not have write permissions when I first backed them up. So, why won't the same problem recur? I am not going to try this solution, yet, since it takes 4 hours for deja-dup to restore before it tells me it cannot do anything (is there some kind of test run I can do on just a portion of the backup?). I want to make sure there is nothing else I can do before proceeding.

For what is meant to be a simple program it does not really make it easy to restore your files. Which newbie is going to know how to get write permissions for the entire file structure before they back it up? Am I just misunderstanding? I hope some one can help, because everything of mine is on that hard drive and I need access to those files.

Comment: try saving a text file to that directory

Comment: which directory?

Comment: the directory in the picture you posted

Comment: The directory in the list isn't yet restored, so it is not in the file system of my computer.